# Autotools project and external libraries on Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, lambda, yocto

I'm trying to build an Autotools project using Yocto ADT Plugin and Eclipse Luna.
I need to include some external libraries to the project and to be more specific the boost libraries.
Let's consider the easiest case scenario: header only library.
I should be able to #include into my project.
I'm trying to compile a test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
        cout << "Hello World" << endl; /* prints Hello World */
        return 0;
}
```

but I'm getting the error: "fatal error: boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or directory"

Of course I have to tell the compiler where to find the library.
I tried to do it in different ways but nothing succeded.
To make some examples: 
Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and Symbols
There I specified the path for downloaded libraries and for compiled libraries (not needed in this case but added for generality):

[image]

The include is correctly reported under project explorer but the error persisted.

Then I tried to work on Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include:

[image]

Still getting the same error.

I tried then to include configuring the Autotools adding the -I option:

[image]

Of course it didn't succeed either.
After every failed build attempt I run a "Clear Project" and "Reconfigure Project" just to be sure to start all over.

The strange thing is that if I select the boost/lambda/lambda.hpp in the editor and I do "Open Declaration" it finds the file:

[image]

At this point I don't know what to do, clearly I'm missing something.

Could you possibly help me ?

Additional Note: If I start an C++ Executable Project using GCC the library is recognized and I have no problems.
So I think the issue is within the Autotools or Yocto ADT.
I even added the boost libraries to my Yocto build and SDK but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to succesfully compile adding to the /src/Makefile.am the include to the libraries.

[image]

Still I don't understand why this is different from changing the Autotools configure flag.

If someone has an answer, please care to explain.

Comment: I suppose that was up to Autotools, because project is being built by Makefile. So, your question is why eclipse include configuration doesn't affect makefile contents?

Comment: Exacly, why Eclipse Autotool settings don’t affect the Makefile.am in my source folder

Comment: 3 years passed, didn't you by any chance figure it out?